# How do I normalize a uniform dist?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

If I have a uniform distribution over A to B, and I want to find the prb of a trial being within 1 std dev, once I have the mean and std dev, how do I normalize this, so the mean is 0 and a std dev is 1. I realize the process is similar to standardizing a nonstd normal dist.

Comment: Try $(X-m)/\sigma$ with $m,\sigma$ chosen appropriately.

Comment: Ok, so if I am given a uniform dist from 7.5 to 20, how do I find the prb of an occurrence being within a std dev. So, integrating, the mean is 13.75 and std dev is 3.06. I use your formula to get -1 < X < 1, which if Integrate over does not give me  a prb. I can do this without normalizing, but I want to learn how to do it by normalizing.